# how to remove the module error while including?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

```
  Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firstApp.seconddir' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
```

here is my code 
http://goo.gl/LOcYI2

I am getting error while including the module in our project.

Answer (score 0):

You should register new module before you use it.

```
Setting module: angular.module('your new module name', [])
Getting module: angular.module('module name')
```

So in your case, change the following line and error will not come.

```
angular.module('firstApp.seconddir').config(Routes);
```

to

```
angular.module('firstApp.seconddir', []).config(Routes);
```

Working demo: http://goo.gl/RvHzqr